# Use type extension on parameter type in constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to somehow use generic on class constructor parameter (`Class2`) instead of defining it on class declaration (`Class1`)?

```js
interface SomeInterface {
    work(): void;
}

class Class1<T extends SomeInterface> {
    constructor(public item: T) { }
}

class Class2 {
    constructor(public item: T extends SomeInterface) { }
}
```

Comment: What's the point? It would be `constructor(public item: SomeInterface) {}` if you don't want the class to be generic.

Comment: But if I do that, it would limit type to only `SomeInterface`. If I were to have another class that would extend that class I could only use methods defined in `SomeInterface`.